# Animate items on Recylerview when scroll ends

Tags: animation, android-recyclerview

in listview or scrollview we can see a little animation when scroll riched and ends.

I want to add that effect on Recylerview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these two GitHub libraries:

**Option 1:** [EverythingMe/overscroll-decor](https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor)

```java
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

// Horizontal
OverScrollDecoratorHelper.setUpOverScroll(recyclerView, OverScrollDecoratorHelper.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
// Vertical
OverScrollDecoratorHelper.setUpOverScroll(recyclerView, OverScrollDecoratorHelper.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```

**Option 2:** [chthai64/overscroll-bouncy-android](https://github.com/chthai64/overscroll-bouncy-android)

```xml
<com.chauthai.overscroll.RecyclerViewBouncy
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Zheentoro Did it helped you? Please mark as solved if it did :)